# What is the use of FromExpression in EF 5?

Tags: .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I am trying to understand whats the use of new `FromExpression` extension method introduced in EF 5 since there are already few different ways you can query entity

Using `FromExpression`:

```
var q = DBContext.Set<MyUser>()
                 .Include(x => x.UserRoles)
                 .ThenInclude(y => y.Role)
                 .Where(x => x.LoginName == loginName);

return await DBContext.FromExpression<MyUser>(() => q).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Without using `FromExpression`:

my old syntax queries using single line

```
var user = DBContext.Set<MyUser>()
                    .Include(x => x.UserRoles)
                    .ThenInclude(y => y.Role)
                    .Where(x => x.LoginName == loginName)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or I can also make use of extension method.

```
public static IQueryable<MyUser> FindUser(this IQueryable<MyUser> source, string loginName)
{
    return source
               .Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(y => y.Role)
               .Where(x => x.LoginName == loginName)
}

var user = DBContext.Set<MyUser>()
               .FindUser(loginName)
               .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

All these scenarios do not need `FromExpression` (although it sort of works with them).

The main (and probably the only) usage of that method is for [Mapping a queryable function to a table-valued function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) as explained in the documentation link with examples, so I'm not going to copy/paste everything written there. The method is essential for that type of mapping since it doesn't support the scalar function mapping with `HasTranslation`.

Shortly, use the "old syntax" for regular LINQ to entities query scenarios, and `FromExpression` only for exposing TVF mapped queryable function.